# does document.getElementsByTagName work in vbscript?

Tags: html, vbscript

Well, it works, it just doesn't produce anything worthwhile:

```
elems = document.getElementById("itemsTable").getElementsByTagName("TR") 
for j = 0 to ubound(elems) - 1      
   ' stuff 
next
```

Well, that won't work, apparently elems is an object, not an array like you'd get in that *fancy javascript*. I'm stuck with vbscript though.

So what do I do to iterate all the rows in a table in vbscript?

Edit: Yes, it's vbscript and it sucks. I don't have a choice here, so don't say "Use jQuery!!".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why using vbscript?

Comment: Because that's what my boss tells me to use.

Comment: Actually you don't get an array in Javascript - you get a NodeList. It's a little different.

Comment: Tell your boss from me that he/she is wrong. Doing browser scripting in vbscript wasn't even a good idea when IE was the best browser around.

Comment: @Joel: Ugh, tell me about it. The good news: in 4 days, no more vbscript (getting a new job).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have correctly stated `getElementsByTagName` does not return an array, hence `UBound()` will not work on it. Treat it as a collection.

For-Eaching through it should work:

```
 Set NodeList = document.getElementById("itemsTable").getElementsByTagName("TR") 
 For Each Elem In NodeList
  ' stuff 
  MsgBox Elem.innerHTML
 Next
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I never did figure out why you have to Set things sometimes and others you don't.

Comment: If I can I'll put a bounty on this, just so you get more rep for the answer. Answering vbscript questions on SO is a thankless job.

Comment: Haha, that's cool. Btw check this page for your question regarding set: http://www.empinstitute.org/caspdoc/html/vbscript_set_statement.htm

Comment: Damn I forgot the "Set" once again. @jcollum (or others), you need to use it when you are trying to pass an object reference. Otherwhise, you will pass a variant, most likely a string (value or name), but for sure not what you intend

Answer (score 1):

If you have IE8+, you can use the ["item" method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So it'd be:

```
Dim elem: Set elem = document.getElementById("itemsTable").getElementsByTagName("TR").item(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

elems isn't an array in JavaScript either, [it is a NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html), it just happens to share some properties with a JavaScript Array object.

I don't know VB, but I assume you could do:

```
for j = 0 to elems.length - 1      
   ' stuff 
next
```

Comment: Note that I said "apparently elems is an object". The object type doesn't have a length.

Comment: Wow. Sounds like VB has a broken DOM implementation.