# Appending element to body in VBScript

Tags: dom, vbscript

I found the you can append an element to an element by ID in VBScript:

```
document.getElementById("td1").appendChild img
```

How can I append to the body? In JavaScript you would do `document.body` but that throws an `object required document.body` in vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `getElementsByTagName("body")` instead ([see MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)).

Note that even though you'll likely have just one `body` tag, this function is designed to return a list of nodes, so you'll need to grab the first element before calling `appendChild` on it.

See also: [does document.getElementsByTagName work in vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1500921/534406)